# Did i miss anything when trying to get selenium working with eclipse?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the next error with this code:

```
package main;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("https://www.google.co.il/");
    

    }
}
```

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

```
at class6_v2/main.main.main(main.java:11)
```

i have added the Jars of selenium to the build path:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyD1I.png)
and checked that the web driver  is the right version  of chrome and in  the class files
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Might want to follow a tutorial since you still need a chromedriver.exe and driver.get("yoururl")

Comment: Yes i  can see that i miss that line, but even after that i have added it im getting the same error:WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.il/");

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up System Property first or set up your chromedriver.exe in to the environment path.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path to your chromedriver.exe)
```

then you declare chrome driver and go to url

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(your url);
```

### Reference

https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html

Comment: Did as you instrcuted but it gives out the samer error :package main;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//mishe//eclipse-workspace//Class6_v2");

     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

 }

}

Comment: You need to include the filename: C://Users//mishe//eclipse-workspace//Class6_v2//chromedriver.exe

Comment: Still same error :<

Comment: I Have found the issue, i have added the external  JARS in  the moudle path insted of the class path,thank you.